# Как обновить значения полученные из одной таблицы в двух других таблицах?

Tags: sql, oracle, update

Есть таблицы A, B и C. Нужно выбрать определенные значения из всех строк таблицы A, а затем для каждой строки таблицы A обновить значения в таблицах B и C.

Псевдокод того, что примерно хочу сделать:

```
SELECT A1, A2, A3, A4 FROM Table A 
    UPDATE Table B SET B2=A2, B3=A3, B4=A4 WHERE B1 = A1
    UPDATE Table C SET C2=A2, C3=A3, C4=A4 WHERE C1 = A1;
```

Как можно этого достичь?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SQL Update values from one table in another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65496776) от участника [@user1107888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107888/user1107888)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65496776

Answer (score 3):

В одном запросе нельзя обновить две таблицы, потребуются два запроса на обновление.

Можно воспользоватся инлайн представлением:

```
update (
    select a.a2, a.a3, a.a4 , b.b2, b.b3, b.b4
    from a
    inner join b on b.b1 = a.a1
) u
set u.b2 = u.a2, u.b3 = u.a3, u.b4 = u.a4;
```

Плюсом такого подхода является то, что обновляется только совпадающие строки, в то время как, с классическим коррелированным подзапросом, необходимо повторить его в `WHERE`.

Еще один лаконичный синтаксис, которым можно достичь желаемого - `MERGE`:

```
merge into b
using a on (a.a1 = b.a1)
when matched then 
    update set b.b2 = a.a2, b.b3 = a.a3, b.b4 = a.a4;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496834/6571020) от участника [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)</sub>